# Set Categories on DateNavigator

Tags: abap, webdynpro

My friend seems to be having some trouble with ABAP. Here's a copy of his question - posted on the SAP community forums.

---

Hey Everyone,
I am trying to mark the DateNavigator with two categories. I made a context called Marking, with attributes Date, Category and Tooltip.

Node: Marking

- Date:
- Category:
- Tooltip:

I filled category attribute with two categories : `e_category-three` and `e_category-four`. I filled the Date attribute with dates. I want some of these dates to be category-three and others category-four.

Currently, all dates are set to the first category (`e_category-three`) and the code looks like this.

```
if ls_host_name-host_name <> host_msg and ls_vm_name-vm_name = vm_msg.
  loop at lt_machine_booking into wa.
    if ls_host_name-host_name = wa-host_name.
        date = wa-reserved_from.
      while date <= wa-reserved_till.
        ls_dates_shared-dates = date.     > i want these dates to be e_category-three
        append ls_dates_shared to lt_dates_shared.
        add 1 to date.
      ENDWHILE.
    endif.
    ENDLOOP.
elseif ls_host_name-host_name <> host_msg and ls_vm_name-vm_name <> vm_msg.
    loop at lt_machine_booking into wa.
      if ls_host_name-host_name = wa-host_name and ls_vm_name-vm_name = wa-vm_name.
        date = wa-reserved_from.
        while date <= wa-reserved_till.
          ls_dates_shared = date.       > i want these dates to be e_category-four
          append ls_dates_shared to lt_dates_shared.
          add 1 to date.
        ENDWHILE.
      endif.
      " ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `ls_dates_shared` is of type marking?

If this is the case you have to fill the fields `ls_dates_shared-category` and `ls_dates_shared-tooltip` explicitly.

Currently this may be filled prior to the code snippet that you give us.  Try something like this:

```
if ls_host_name-host_name <> host_msg and ls_vm_name-vm_name = vm_msg.
  loop at lt_machine_booking into wa.
    if ls_host_name-host_name = wa-host_name.
        date = wa-reserved_from.
      while date <= wa-reserved_till.
        ls_dates_shared-dates = date.     "i want these dates to be e_category-three"
        ls_dates_shared-category = e_category-three.
        "ls_dates-tooltip = appropriate_tooltip for e_category-three"
        append ls_dates_shared to lt_dates_shared.
        add 1 to date.
      ENDWHILE.
    endif.
  ENDLOOP.

elseif ls_host_name-host_name <> host_msg and ls_vm_name-vm_name <> vm_msg.
  loop at lt_machine_booking into wa.
    if ls_host_name-host_name = wa-host_name and ls_vm_name-vm_name = wa-vm_name.
      date = wa-reserved_from.
      while date <= wa-reserved_till.
        ls_dates_shared = date.       "i want these dates to be e_category-four"
        ls_dates_shared-category = e_category-four.
        "ls_dates-tooltip = appropriate_tooltip for e_category-four"
        append ls_dates_shared to lt_dates_shared.
        add 1 to date.
      ENDWHILE.
    endif.
...
```